# Basis for solutions hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, hypergeometric-functions

In the book "Theorie der gewöhnlichen Differentialgleichungen" by Bieberbach, page 240, there is a solution to the hypergeometric differential equation 
$z(z-1)w^{\prime \prime}+(2z-1)w^{\prime}+\frac{w}{4}=0$. 
This equation corresponds to the hypergeometric function $F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z)$. In general, a basis for the solution of the hypergeometric differential equation $$z(z-1)w^{\prime \prime}+(z(1+\alpha+\beta)-\gamma )w^{\prime}+\alpha \beta w=0$$ is given by $F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma;z)$ and $z^{1-\gamma}F(\alpha-\gamma+1, \beta-\gamma+1,2-\gamma; z)$. However, when $\alpha = \beta=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\gamma=1$, these two solutions coincide. In order to remedy this, the author considers for the first basis element the function $w_1=F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z)$ and for the second
$w_2=F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z)+F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z) \log z$, where $F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z)=(\frac{\partial F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma;z)}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma;z)}{\partial \beta}+2\frac{\partial F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma;z)}{\partial \gamma})_{\alpha=\frac{1}{2},\beta=\frac{1}{2}, \gamma=1}$. Of course one can check that this is really a solution, but my question is from where, exactly, comes the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}+2\frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}$? How one should get this idea?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be submitted as a comment. Your question should be adjusted in view of the output of the Maple 2017.3 command

```
dsolve(z*(z-1)*((D@@2)(w))(z)+(2*z-1)*(D(w))(z)+2*w(z) = 0);
```

$$w \left( z \right) ={\it \_C1}\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/2-i/2\sqrt {7},1/2-i/2\sqrt {7};\,-i\sqrt {7}+1;\,{z}^{-1})}
{z}^{-1/2+i/2\sqrt {7}}+{\it \_C2}\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/2+i/2\sqrt {7},1/2+i/2\sqrt {7};\,i\sqrt {7}+1;\,{z}^{-1})}
{z}^{-1/2-i/2\sqrt {7}}
 $$
as well as the output of the Mathematica 11.2.0.0 command

```
DSolve[z*(z - 1)*w''[z] + (2 z - 1)*w'[z] + 2*w[z] == 0, w[z], z]
```

$$\left\{\left\{w(z)\to c_1 P_{\frac{1}{2} i \left(i+\sqrt{7}\right)}(2 z-1)+c_2 Q_{\frac{1}{2} i \left(i+\sqrt{7}\right)}(2 z-1)\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: @ user64494 : Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean! Could you be more precise? What are $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: @Cyrus: The outputs are not of the form $ F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;z)$ stated by you. As usualy, $C\,(c)$ stand for constants.

Comment: @ user64494: Yes! you are right, I edited the question, the last coefficeitn should be $\frac{1}{4}$ not $2$!

Comment: @Cyrus: In the case $+\frac 1 4 w(z)$ Maple outputs $$w \left( z \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{\it EllipticK} \left( \sqrt {z}
 \right) +{\it \_C2}\,{\it EllipticCK} \left( \sqrt {z} \right)
 $$. The executed code on demand.

Comment: @Cyrus: Also Mathematica performs $$ \left\{\left\{w(z)\to \frac{2 c_1 K\left(\frac{1}{2} (2-2 z)\right)}{\pi }+c_2 Q_{-\frac{1}{2}}(2 z-1)\right\}\right\}$$ in this case.

Comment: This computation is correct because the solution should be the elliptic integral as indicated in the book. However, my question was something else, by the way what if P and Q in the above?

Comment: @Cyrus: EllipticK and LegendreQ correspondently. What do you mean by " the hypergeometric differential equation "?

Comment: @ user64494: The DE given above in the question.

Comment: @Cyrus: Sorry, still don't understand your statement " In general, a basis for the solution of the hypergeometric differential equation is given by $ F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma;z)$ and  $ z^{1-\gamma}F(\alpha-\gamma+1, \beta-\gamma+1,2-\gamma; z)$ ".

Comment: The general HPG equation is: $z(z-1)w^{\prime \prime}+(z(1+\alpha+\beta)-\gamma )w^{\prime}+\alpha \beta w=0$. The above HPG equation is when $\alpha=\beta=1/2$ and $\gamma=1$.

Comment: It is true that some elliptic integrals and some Legendre functions may be written as hypergeometric functions.  And Maple/Mathematica prefer the elliptic integral or Legendre function forms (if they exist) to the hypergeometric forms.  But of course the hypergeometric forms are still correct solutions of the DE.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: The conversion of the Maple solution for $ \alpha =  \frac 1 2 ,\, \beta  = \frac 1 2 ,\, \gamma =1 $ to hypergeom is $$ w \left( z \right) =1/2\,{\it \_C1}\,\pi\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/2,1/2;\,1;\,z)}+1/2\,{\it \_C2}\,\pi\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/2,1/2;\,1;\,-z+1)}
,$$ not the form in the question.

Comment: @user64494 ... And Maple used a hypergeometric with argument $1-z$ and not $z$ because the other solution is logarithmic at $0$, as shown by the form in the question.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Can you kindly base your claim? TIA.